How to update column table
I am trying to create a SQL query to update a column in my table as shown here.
Driver table:



ID
TripTotal




1
NULL


2
NULL


3
NULL


4
NULL



Trip table:



TRIP ID
DRIVER ID
TRIP




1
1
1


2
1
2


3
1
3


4
2
1


5
2
2


6
3
1


7
4
1


8
4
2



The result set should look like this:



ID
TripTotal




1
3


2
2


3
1


4
2


5
0



When there is no trip rows, the result should return 0.
I tried using:
UPDATE driver 
SET totaltripmade = (SELECT COUNT(Lnum) FROM TRIP);

I don't know how to use GROUP BY to calculate for distinct count. The result works to show the count for all trips not by user.

Some inconsistency here, where did you find driver 5?

Follow @TimBigeleisen's advice, don't store such calculated values. Redundancy leads to inconsistency!

Rather than updating, I suggest just using a select report which generates the trip totals you want to see:
SELECT d.id, COUNT(t.trip) AS TripTotal
FROM driver d
LEFT JOIN trip t
    ON t.driver_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY d.id;

Note that we use a left join here to ensure that every driver appears in the output, even if there are no corresponding trip records in the second table.

It looks like OP wants COUNT(), not SUM().

I suggest using case when, like this,
UPDATE driver
SET triptotal = (
CASE
WHEN EXISTS (
select 1 from trip
where trip.driver_id = driver.id)
THEN (
select count(*) from trip
where trip.driver_id = driver.id)
ELSE 0
END
);



update Driver
set TripTotal = (select count(0) from Trip t where d.id = t.driverId)


**can be ignored**

create table Driver (
    id int,
    TripTotal int
)

insert Driver (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4)

create table Trip  (
    tripId int,
    driverId int,
    trip int
)

insert Trip values (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,1,3),(4,2,1)


You don't need a FROM clause. Just update Driver d set .... Anyway, I like Tim Biegeleisen's answer much better, because such a TripTotal column should not exist in a well-designed database in the first place. I would remove all the can-be-ignored stuff from the answer btw. and rather put that in a demo in https://dbfiddle.uk/ instead (e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/Jap9-Snk).

As to the code: 1. SQL statements end with a semicolon. 2. It is insert into driver ..., not insert driver .... 3. COUNT(0) tells the DBMS to count all rows for which a zero is not null, which is true for all rows. The DBMS will optimize this internally to COUNT(*), but why make the DBMS do this at all? Just write COUNT(*) right away yourself.

just recap  - "how to update column table"

You can try this also:
update driver d LEFT OUTER JOIN (
             select a.driverid, count(a.driverid) as "no_of_trips"
               from  trip a
              group by a.driverid 
              having COUNT(a.driverid)> 0) x
      ON d.id= x.driverid
   set d.triptotal=  COALESCE(x.no_of_trips,0)

